# How to use vim-slime from within a single tmux session?

Tags: vim, python, tmux

I'm trying to integrate ipython and vim through a single tmux session using the popular vim plugin "vim-slime." The problem is that while I can get it to work fine provided that vim is opened in a separate tmux window (or using gvim), if I try to send lines of code to a different pane in the same window, at best I wind up sending it to the vim session I'm currently using.

Really what I want in my setup is vim on the right-hand side of the screen, ipython on the upper-left, and a regular command-line on the bottom left. I don't really want to be opening and managing multiple sessions and windows.

Is there a simple way to do this that I just don't know about because of my relative inexperience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I was having exactly the same problem, which is what brought me to this question. I have a split session, vim code on the left and a scheme prompt on the right.

My problem was, I thought the session name was the socket name, but they are two different things. I had named the session '0', for the 0-th window, but in fact, the SOCKET is named 'default' despite the session name I specified.

To get a list of the tmux sockets run:
`lsof -U | grep "^tmux"`

I found that from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333291/is-it-possible-to-find-tmux-sockets-currently-in-use

The above was helpful to see the actual names of the sockets.

That is what you put in the first prompt. I was putting '0', which was the name of my session, but it was not working. 'default' is what is needed there despite the fact I had named the session.

Then, at the second prompt, I entered (index-0 window, index-1 pane):
`:0.1`

Voila! Finally! It was working. Brilliant, now side-by-side
editing!

Comment: This solved it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the target pane with `<c-c>v` or `:SlimeConfig`. The default is `:`, which is "current window, current pane." See `:help slime-tmux`.

Instead, navigate to the Tmux pane you want to send the text to (the one with iPython running), and from the shell run `echo $TMUX_PANE` or `tmux run "echo #{pane_id}"` to [find the correct pane ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340314/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-active-pane-id-for-tmux-panes).

Comment: Does not work for me. `<C-c>v`  just brings up VISUAL mode.
Plus I believe the $TMUX_PANE is not the information sought.
Pressing `<C-b>x` (command to kill a pane) brings up a confirmation request that includes the n° of the pane. This number differs from $TMUX_PANE  *and* appears to be the correct information to answer the OP's requirement

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch tmux.
2. `Ctrl-b %` to split vertically.
3. `Ctrl-b [left arrow]` to move to left hand pane
4. `Ctrl-b "` to split left hand pane horizontally. You'll now have 3 command lines.
5. `Ctrl-b [up arrow]` to move to upper left hand pane, followed by `ipython`.
6. `Ctrl-b [right arrow]` to move to right hand pane.
7. Launch vim on your Python code.
8. Send a line using `Ctrl-C Ctrl-C`, accept socket name as `default`, and enter `:0.0` to select the IPython pane.

`default` and `0:0` are the socket name and pane id respectively.

Comment: This does not address the issue described in my OP.

Comment: @Ram Yes it did : following the steps that Simon gave, I obtain exactly the configuration the OP asked for.